# Replace all `!stuffs.IsEmpty()' by `stuffs.Any()' with ReSharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I work on an application where we use this `IEnumerable` extension :

```
public static bool IsEmpty<TSource>([NoEnumeration] this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    return !source.Any(); // not actual implementation
}
```

But a lot of usage are like this :

```
var notEmpty = !stuffs.IsEmpty()
```

And here I got a double (and useless) negation.

I would like to re-factor automatically all this usage to be like this :

```
var notEmpty = stuffs.Any()
```

What is the simplest way to do it ? with ReSharper ?

Comment: If you're using VS2015, Create a Roslyn extension that does this.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov you could, but this would be an overkill for this task.

Comment: @Igal Whatcha doin here ;)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov other than monitoring the [ReSharper] tag? Oh nothing :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using ReSharper's [Structural Search and Replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Navigation_and_Search__Structural_Search_and_Replace.html). You can even save a pattern (to the team-shared settings) to create a custom highlighting in the editor (go to *Options | Code Inspection | Custom Patterns*).

[image: R# SSR]